# Synchronizing two senders and receiver threads

Tags: multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have the following problem, I have 2 senders, that send one after each other, and only after 2 of them sent the message, I want a receiver to start receiving  and then wait for the next two sends, e.g.
S1
S2
Rec
S1
S2 Rec...

```
semOne = threading.Semaphore(value = 1)
semTwo = threading.Semaphore(value = 0)
semRecNotify = threading.Semaphore(value = 0)

def senderOne():
    while True:
        semOne.acquire()
        print("Sender One")
        semTwo.release()

def senderTwo():
    while True:
        semTwo.acquire()
        print("Sender Two")
        semOne.release()
        semRecNotify.release()

def receiver():
    while True:
        semRecNotify.acquire()
        print("Receiver")
```

Using `semOne` and `semTwo`, I managed to synchronize 2 senders and using `semRecNotify` I tried (unsuccessfully) make sure that we enter receiver only after 2 consecutive sends. I am not able to get wanted functionality.

Please take a note that this is not language specific problem, I am just trying to understand myself how to properly use semaphores for synchronization.
Is there more general/mathematical approach to tackle this problem in general?

Comment: I don't understand what the point of this is. Does receiving have any side-effect? If not, then why do you care about when receiving starts? That's internal logic of the program, nobody cares about that, surely?

Comment: Sorry for late replay, somehow I did not get notified about your replay. So idea is to implement Time Division Multiplex. Previously I have done it using global flags. IMHO usage of global variables to synchronize things, especially in multi-threading program is not the wisest thing to do. Therefore I tried to use semaphores instead. Basically, I would like to achieve precise synchronization between two senders and receiver.

Comment: But I don't think a receiver waits for two packets in TDM. I think you are imagining a requirement that does not exist.

Comment: Based on Wiki page, in my case I should synchronize two senders, where sender 2 sends only after sender 1 has stopped transmitting, and so on?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is no requirement for the receiver to wait.

Comment: Okay so in this simple example, since I have only 2 senders I can use 2 semaphores to synchronize them. What if I had more than 2 senders and I would want to synchronize them in TDM fashion. I feel solution using semaphores would be too complicated.